# I use WordPress and would like to display the height and weight box on all product pages except for the accessories category,how to do the exception?

Tags: javascript, php, css, hook-woocommerce

here is the i used to display height and weight boxes on product pages:

```
// Display custom field on single product page
    function d_extra_product_field(){
        $value = isset( $_POST['extra_product_field'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['extra_product_field'] ) : '';
        printf( '<div><label>%s</label><br><textarea name="extra_product_field" value="%s"></textarea></div>', __( '<br><br><br> Enter your order notes' ), esc_attr( $value ) );
    }
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'd_extra_product_field', 9 );

    // validate when add to cart
    function d_extra_field_validation($passed, $product_id, $qty){

        if( isset( $_POST['extra_product_field'] ) && sanitize_text_field( $_POST['extra_product_field'] ) == '' ){
            $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
            wc_add_notice( sprintf( __( '%s يرجى إدخال ملاحظات الطلب لإضافة المنتج الى السلة.' ), $product->get_title() ), 'error' );
            return false;
        }

        return $passed;

    }
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'd_extra_field_validation', 10, 3 );

     // add custom field data in to cart
    function d_add_cart_item_data( $cart_item, $product_id ){

        if( isset( $_POST['extra_product_field'] ) ) {
            $cart_item['extra_product_field'] = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['extra_product_field'] );
        }

        return $cart_item;

    }
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'd_add_cart_item_data', 10, 2 );

    // load data from session
    function d_get_cart_data_f_session( $cart_item, $values ) {

        if ( isset( $values['extra_product_field'] ) ){
            $cart_item['extra_product_field'] = $values['extra_product_field'];
        }

        return $cart_item;

    }
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_cart_item_from_session', 'd_get_cart_data_f_session', 20, 2 );


    //add meta to order
    function d_add_order_meta( $item_id, $values ) {

        if ( ! empty( $values['extra_product_field'] ) ) {
            woocommerce_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'extra_product_field', $values['extra_product_field'] );           
        }
    }
    add_action( 'woocommerce_add_order_item_meta', 'd_add_order_meta', 10, 2 );

    // display data in cart
    function d_get_itemdata( $other_data, $cart_item ) {

        if ( isset( $cart_item['extra_product_field'] ) ){

            $other_data[] = array(
                'name' => __( 'Your extra field text' ),
                'value' => sanitize_text_field( $cart_item['extra_product_field'] )
            );

        }

        return $other_data;

    }
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'd_get_itemdata', 10, 2 );


    // display custom field data in order view
    function d_dis_metadata_order( $cart_item, $order_item ){

        if( isset( $order_item['extra_product_field'] ) ){
            $cart_item_meta['extra_product_field'] = $order_item['extra_product_field'];
        }

        return $cart_item;

    }
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_product', 'd_dis_metadata_order', 10, 2 );


    // add field data in email
    function d_order_email_data( $fields ) { 
        $fields['extra_product_field'] = __( 'Your extra field text' ); 
        return $fields; 
    } 
    add_filter('woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields', 'd_order_email_data');

    // again order
    function d_order_again_meta_data( $cart_item, $order_item, $order ){

        if( isset( $order_item['extra_product_field'] ) ){
            $cart_item_meta['extra_product_field'] = $order_item['extra_product_field'];
        }

        return $cart_item;

    }
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_again_cart_item_data', 'd_order_again_meta_data', 10, 3 );





add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_enqueue_wc_cart_fragments' );
function custom_enqueue_wc_cart_fragments() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wc-cart-fragments' );
}
```

The weight and height field is mandatory, so I used css code below and the box was actually hidden in the accessories category, but even though it disappeared, it is still mandatory and can't add product to the cart for all products in accessories category: